# make ajax upload abort-able up to just before upload progress is complete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have this ajax file upload form with an abort(); function. which is triggered by clicking cancel anchor:

```
   $('#cancel').click(function(){ 
     ajaxFileUpload.abort();
     $('#message').html('cancelled');
 });
```

and this anchor is hidden when the success function returns 'successfullyUploaded':

```
if(response == 'successfullyUploaded') {$('#cancel').hide(); });
```

at which point the files are uploaded and it's too late to cancel the upload. For the most part it works pretty well. However if someone clicks 'cancel' in the instant between the files uploading on the php page which handles the upload, and the page containing the form receiving the success data it will say 'cancelled' but in fact the upload has been completed. So I was wondering if there was some way to detect when the file upload is at, say, 95% complete, and at that point, hide the 'cancel' anchor. Is this at all possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is very possible, but I wouldn't claim it to be the best option. The time span between a successful upload and getting the data back should be at tops ~200ms average. I personally wouldn't worry about this, but if I had to, I'd send another Ajax request when one clicks the cancel button to ensure that the upload hasn't finished yet before 'cancelling' the upload.

Comment: I know it seems a little trivial. I just don't like the idea that in the unlikely event it happens, the user is getting incorrect information

Comment: I see. It is a little hard to reproduce otherwise I'd take a deeper look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon abort you may send a second AJAX request to the server telling that the upload have been canceled and the uploaded file (if present) must be deleted.

As you receive success response from the second request you can set **#message** to **canceled**

Comment: a valid solution, I will consider this. Thank you for the suggestion.